# ServerValidateEventArgs and custom validation control in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I'm a beginner in ASP.NET, just a question on the custom validation, we know that it works in this way:

```
protected void customValidation_ServerValidate(Object source, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
{
   if(e.Value...)
   {
    ...
   } else
   {
      e.IsValid = false;
   }
} //customValidation is the id of the custom validation control
```

but how the value of `e.isValid` get transferred to the validation's IsValid property?why we have to use ServerValidateEventArgs instead of coding like;

```
...
} else
{
    customValidation.IsValid = false;
}
```

isn't this approach more sensible? setting the validation control's isValid to false? why via ServerValidateEventArgs instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say you have several controls that use the same custom validation. You only want to indicate those controls which are invalid. This is where `ServerValidateEventArgs`  comes in.

This will then be used to indicate which control(s) have failed validation on the page.

E.G.

**ASPX**

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtCustomDate" />
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" OnServerValidate="cstvDate_ServerValidate" 
     ControlToValidate="txtCustomDate" ID="ctValDate1" ></asp:CustomValidator>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtCustomDate2" />
<!-- Same Logic for validation -->
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" OnServerValidate="cstvDate_ServerValidate" 
      ControlToValidate="txtCustomDate2" ID="ctValDate2" ></asp:CustomValidator>
```

**Code behind**

```
protected void customValidation_ServerValidate(Object source, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
{
   if(e.Value...)
   {
    ...
   } else
   {
      e.IsValid = false;
   }
}
```

The validation method is identified by the `OnServerValidate` attribute. The validation control passes information about itself via the `source` parameter and the validation event via the `e` parameter.

For more information see:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator?view=netframework-4.7.2
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.servervalidateeventargs?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: sorry, still sth I'm not  quite clear. How come the custom validators don't have id? the 'customValidation_ServerValidate' belong to which validation control?

Comment: so those two validation controls have the same ID and share the same event handler?

Comment: Sorry, I need more coffee! The IDs should be different. I've changed my answer to reflect this. They do share the same event handler, via the `OnServerValidate ` attribute. If you were to try this with two controls with the same ID you would get all sorts of errors.